# Converting QVariant to QVector<int>

Tags: c++, qt

It's easy to convert a `QVector<int>` to `QVariant` but the otherwise is not trivial

```
QVector<int> v;
v.append(1);
v.append(2);
v.append(3);
QVariant var = QVariant::fromValue(v);
QVector v2(var.toList().toVector()); // fails, returns QVector<QVariant>
```

First of all: is there any Qt idiom to automatically convert that back or do I have to iterate manually over the `var.toList()` collection?

Besides, the whole operation is quite costly: first a `QList` is constructed, then a `QVector` is constructed, then the `QVector` is copied back into `v2`. Is there any way to convert a `QVariant` directly into `QVector`? Does Qt support rvalue references itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `QVector<int> v2 = var.value<QVector<int>>();`
You can test that by the following piece of code:

```
QVector<int> v2 = var.value<QVector<int>>();

qDebug() << "Size: " << v2.size();
for(int i = 0; i < v2.size(); i++)
    qDebug() << v2.at(i);
```

Take a look at the method [value](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#value) on Qt documentation:

> Returns the stored value converted to the template type T. Call canConvert() to find out whether a type can be converted. If the value cannot be converted, a default-constructed value will be returned.

Comment: Does this actually work to convert to `QVector<int>`? I'll upvote if it does, but I'd like confirmation first :)

Comment: @hyde Yes, I tested that code before posting the answer, and I edited the answer and added a simple test.

Comment: Yeah. The one thing to note is, for this to work, the original value assigned to the `QVariant` must match what you get back with `value`. So for example changing `QVector` to `QList`, both original value, and the value taken from `QVariant` must be changed.

Comment: As for the move semantics, Qt 5.7 supports them, so this solves the second concern too: `QtCore/qvector.h:    QVector<T> &operator=(QVector<T> &&other) Q_DECL_NOTHROW`